# how to add row in a many to many self relationship table and be coherence?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a many to many self relationship. So I have this two Tables.

```
TableA
{
    IDTableA;
    Data;
}

Realtionships
{
    IDTableA;
    IDTableARelated;
}
```

I would like to know now, for a row in TableA, which rows in TableA are related with this row.

I have two options, to add only one row to Relationsips table, for example (1,2), in this case 2 is related with 1, but how 2 is related with 1, 1 is related with 2 too. But this has the problem how to avoid duplicates. For example, if one precess is trying to add (1,2) and other precess try to add (2,1), how could I avoid this duplicate?

So the second option it is to add always the two rows, (1,2) and (2,1). But I am not sure how to ensure that always I will have the two rows. I was thinking in this two queries:

```
Begin tran
insert into Relations(IDTableA, IDTableARelated) VALUES(1,2);
insert into Relations(IDTableA, IDTableARelated) VALUES(2,1);
commint


Begin tran
delete TableAB where IDTableA = 1 and IDTableARelated = 2;
delete TableAB where IDTableA = 2 and IDTableARelated = 1;
commit
```

But in my tests, I can get results in which at the end I have only one of the rows. For example, if the row (1,2) exists, it can happens this:

- First process try to add the row (1,2).
- Second process try to delete the row (2,1);
- First process try to add (2,1);
- Second process try to delete (1,2);

the final result is that I have only the row (2,1), so it is no coherence, I should have the row (1,2) too.

Really in my case I could choose the option one or option two, but I would like to know if there are some way with tsql to ensure the coherence of the data, if it is option 1, to avoid duplicates, if it is the second solution, ensure that always I will have the two rows.

Thanks.

EDIT: I add the script of the database with:

```
USE [TestRelacionN-N]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TablaA]    Script Date: 26/05/2019 11:07:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TablaA](
    [IDTablaA] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Dato] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TablaA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDTablaA] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TableAWithTableA]    Script Date: 26/05/2019 11:07:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableAWithTableA](
    [IDTableA] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [IDTableARelated] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableAWithTableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDTableA] ASC,
    [IDTableARelated] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TablaA] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[TablaA] ([IDTablaA], [Dato]) VALUES (1, N'Dato01')
INSERT [dbo].[TablaA] ([IDTablaA], [Dato]) VALUES (2, N'Dato02')
INSERT [dbo].[TablaA] ([IDTablaA], [Dato]) VALUES (3, N'Dato03')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TablaA] OFF
INSERT [dbo].[TableAWithTableA] ([IDTableA], [IDTableARelated]) VALUES (1, 2)
```

Comment: This question is not very clear at all. Are you able to add some actual table and query scripts for ,e to look at?

Comment: I have add the two tables with the data. The scripts are the two scripts that I have added at first, the first transaction when I want to add rows and the second transaction to delete rows.

Comment: What is this modelling? it seems like it doesn't matter whether you have an (unordered) duplicate or not. How many records do you expect in these tables?

Comment: _I would like to know now, for a row in TableA, which rows in TableA are related with this row_ and _how to avoid duplicates_ these are two completely different problems. I see that you have a technical problem here but I don't understand what you are trying to model here.